# how to set multiple lines in a doxygen paragraph?

Tags: doxygen

The following doyxygen comments:

```
/// @par title
/// content1
/// content2
///
```

will merge "content1" and "content2" into a single line as follows:

```
**title**
  content1 content2
```

But how to set multiple lines in a doxygen paragraph, i.e.

```
**title**
  content1
  content2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to start a new paragraph then the simplest route is to use HTML:  You can use `<br>` to break a line.

```
/// @par title
/// content1 <br>
/// content2
///
```

If you want a new paragraph, then just insert a blank line between content1 and content2.

However, it looks a bit like you are starting a list of items.  In that case then consider using a bulleted list:

```
/// @par title
///  * content1
///  * content2
///
```

More on bulleted lists in the Doxygen manual.

Answer (score 4):

Put a blank line between paragraphs

```
    /// @par title
    /// content1
    ///
    /// content2
    ///
```

I do believe a `<BR>` or even a `\n` will work too

```
    /// @par title
    /// content1<BR>
    /// content2<BR>
    ///
```